# vim call function on a group in substitute string

Tags: regex, vim, substitution, function-call

how to call a function from the substitute string in vim? When i have:

`%s/regex/string/g` and i want the group as argument and replace it with the return value of the function:

`%s/regex/call function(\1)/g` so the group #1 will be the argument of the function, and the return value of the function will replace all the matches in buffer.

is it posible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To use a vimscript expression you need to add `\=` to your replacement string:

```
%s/regex/\= function(submatch(1))/g
```

Comment: @microo8 Thanks for your comment. I've added the missing `submatch` call to get `\1`.

Comment: Note see ``:h sub-replace-expression`` for more details.

Comment: This somehow does not work when there is a character before the function call.